# Insert trigger with conditional update on previous insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table t. I want to make insert trigger(s) that do the following:

1. `update t set dbupddate=getdate() where t.code in (select code from inserted)`
2. `insert into someothertable select * from inserted`
3. IFF step 2) is succesful, then

   `update t set transfer_date=getdate()`

   (but, even if step 2 wasnt successful, do not rollback step 1!)

The question is what trigger(s) to use and how, so that I can ensure step 1 runs always and step 3 only when step 2 does not throw errors.

The reason I want this is to be able to manually check for unsuccessful step 2 inserts by making a query on rows with transfer_date=null.

Comment: why would you not be able to use `@@ROWCOUNT`here ?

Comment: Because of what david mentions...

Comment: So you are essentially trying to make a trigger that will partially insert some data. The reason this is a difficult task is because a database transaction should be atomic, meaning the entire statement works or the entire statement fails. You are trying to break that important piece of how databases work. It is possible to do this but questionable at best. If you really want some help you need to post some table definitions and such. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

> IFF step 2) is succesful, then

A trigger runs in the transaction of the DML statement that started the trigger.  If step 2) fails, the original INSERT will be rolled back.

Comment: no, that is only when an error occurs in step 2, not if step 2 just did not inserted any records. In this case that should not happen that I agree with

Comment: David, let me see if I understand: If step 2 fails, then the original DML transaction will fail, and thus nothing will happen...right? So, can I maybe begin a try-catch transaction-within-the-orignal-DML-transaction which will include step 2? Or maybe, put step 1 into a first trigger and steps 2,3 in a last trigger?

Comment: Can't say without understanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I made some edits to clarify. I'm trying to have step 1 always execute, but 3 only if 2 doesn't throw error.

Comment: Then use a stored procedure, not a trigger.

Comment: Hmmm. I would like to use the inserted table though. Should the trigger copy inserted to a ##table and have the spc read from it?

Comment: Use the OUTPUT clause to retrieve the inserted rows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: unfortunately, I have no control over the original insert statement. I can only make the trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171783/discussion-between-george-menoutis-and-david-browne-microsoft).